# Qt with qwt runtime error: QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, runtime, qwt

I am trying to make a app using qt 5.4.1(and qwt 6.1.2).Here is my environment:

- Windows 7 x64
- visual studio 2012
- Qt5.4.1 static
- qwt6.1.2

and I have built qwt with my Qt static libs successfully.
I creat a  widget class inherited from QwtPlot,and I creat a mainWindow which has a object of that widget. Then I build the project.
However,there is a runtime error:**QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget**.

---

This is my widget class inherited from QwtPlot:

```html
#pragma once

#include <QWT/qwt_plot.h>
#include <QWT/qwt_plot_curve.h>



class DrawWidget: public QwtPlot
{
public:
 DrawWidget(QWidget *parent );
 ~DrawWidget(void);
};
```

```html
DrawWidget::DrawWidget(QWidget *parent )
  :   QwtPlot( parent ),
  carve(NULL)
{
 
}
```

And the follow is my mainWindow class:

```html
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H


#include "DrawWidget.h"

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
 Q_OBJECT


public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
 

private:
    DrawWidget *drawWidget;
 

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

```html
  MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
   :QMainWindow(parent)
  {
     QWidget *widget = new QWidget(this);
     this->setCentralWidget(widget);
  QHBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout(widget);

  drawWidget = new DrawWidget(widget);

     mainLayout->addWidget(drawWidget);
     centralWidget()->setLayout(mainLayout);

  }
```

And this is my main.cpp:

```html
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtPlugin>
Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(QWindowsIntegrationPlugin);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
 MainWindow w;
 w.resize(1000,600);
 w.show();
 return a.exec();
}
```

I build this project in release version.Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: Is it working in debug? Also are you sure that you are using release version of qwt library for release version of your application?

Comment: HI demonplus! I am depressed that the debug version is also not working.In debug version, it even cannot build successfully.I add qwt.lib to Additional Dependencies,So I think I am  using release version of qwt library for release version of my application.

Comment: This error shows than you run debug build with release version `qwt` . Fix lib including in pro file:

``CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
  message(Release build!)
  LIBS+=-Lc:/qwt-6.0.1/bin -lqwt
...
}
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
  message(Debug build!)
  LIBS+=-Lc:/qwt-6.0.1/bin -lqwtd
...
}``

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem few weeks ago in my case the problem was the additional library. Make sure that you got builds of the additional library debug for debug building and release for release building. Add AdditionalLibraryDebug/bin folder to the Path environment variable when you build Debug Version and AdditionalLibraryRelease/bin when you build Release version (not both in same time)

Good Luck :) i solved my problem on this way. :)

Comment: Thank you gele! I have moved qwt.lib to C:\Qt\5.4.1\qt-5.4.1-x86-msvc2012-static\lib , and qwt.dll to C:\Qt\5.4.1\qt-5.4.1-x86-msvc2012-static\bin, and all qwt_*.h / qwt_*.cpp to C:\Qt\5.4.1\qt-5.4.1-x86-msvc2012-compact-static\include\QWT. In my project , I have added qwt.lib to Additional Dependencies, and $(QTDIR)\include\QWT to Additional include directories. BUT , it doesn't work. The runtime error  is still there! Is there any other things I have to do?

Comment: The error is coast by the additional library, make sure you have builded for release version with **same version of compiler** that is build your Qt version that can make problems too.

Answer (score 0):

I found this very useful

http://www.itk.org/Wiki/VTK/FAQ#Shared_builds_of_VTK_and_debugging_QVTKWidget_using_Visual_Studio

It happens that libraries depend on the debug version of VTK so you have to build both release and debug and be sure to add the path in the debugging properties.